# Determining Dependencies and Installing from Directory

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, repository, dependencies, dpkg

I have a directory with all Dependencies in .deb format.

But there are lots of them. I need only those that i need for gimp.

```
biggenius@hacbook:~/Desktop/rocks/packages$ dpkg-deb -I gimp_2.6.12-1ubuntu1_i386.deb 
 new debian package, version 2.0.
 size 4722192 bytes: control archive= 7927 bytes.
    1894 bytes,    27 lines      control              
   15660 bytes,   219 lines      md5sums              
     353 bytes,    14 lines   *  postinst             #!/bin/sh
     160 bytes,     5 lines   *  postrm               #!/bin/sh
     331 bytes,    11 lines   *  preinst              #!/bin/sh
     245 bytes,    14 lines   *  prerm                #!/bin/sh
 Package: gimp
 Version: 2.6.12-1ubuntu1
 Architecture: i386
 Maintainer: Ubuntu Desktop Team <ubuntu-desktop@lists.ubuntu.com>
 Installed-Size: 12814
 Depends: libgimp2.0 (>= 2.6.12), libgimp2.0 (<= 2.6.12-z), gimp-data (>= 2.6.12), gimp-data (<= 2.6.12-z), python-gtk2 (>= 2.8.0), libaa1 (>= 1.4p5), libbabl-0.0-0, libc6 (>= 2.15), libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4), libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.0.2), libdbus-glib-1-2 (>= 0.88), libexif12, libfontconfig1 (>= 2.8.0), libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0), libgegl-0.0-0 (>= 0.0.22), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.2), libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0), libjpeg8 (>= 8c), liblcms1 (>= 1.15-1), libmng1 (>= 1.0.10), libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.18.0), libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4), libpoppler-glib8 (>= 0.18), librsvg2-2 (>= 2.14.4), libtiff4, libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 (>= 1.3.10), libwmf0.2-7 (>= 0.2.8.4), libx11-6, libxext6, libxfixes3, libxmu6, libxpm4, zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4), python (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2), python2.7
 Recommends: ghostscript
 Suggests: gimp-help-en | gimp-help, gimp-data-extras, gvfs-backends, libasound2
 Provides: gimp-helpbrowser, gimp-python
 Section: graphics
 Priority: optional
 Homepage: http://www.gimp.org
 Description: The GNU Image Manipulation Program
  GIMP is an advanced picture editor. You can use it to edit, enhance,
  and retouch photos and scans, create drawings, and make your own
  images. Lots of tools are available; you can sharpen and resize photos,
  and remove dust and red-eyes, for example.
  .
  It has a large collection of professional-level editing tools and
  filters, similar to the ones you might find in PhotoShop. Numerous
  fine-control settings and features like layers, paths, masks, and
  scripting give you total control over your images.
  .
  Many image file formats are supported, including JPEG, PhotoShop
  (.psd), and Paint Shop Pro (.psp) files. It can also be used to scan
  and print photos.
 Original-Maintainer: Ari Pollak <ari@debian.org>
```

How can I install only these decencies from Directory?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can `aptitude -s install gimp` to have aptitude resolve the dependencies for you and then use that list to find out which packages you need to install.

You can also setup a local repository with all your deb-files using `reprepro`, temporarily put your repository into `/etc/apt/sources.list` as the only repository and then simply `aptitude install gimp`.

The most sensible way however would be to just `aptitude install gimp` ... or don't you have an internet connection?

Comment: I dont have internet on that PC. I have setup a local repos in there. How can i force apt to install thoes depencies from my local repo instead of repo from Internet?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/174816/forcing-to-install-dependencies-from-custom-repostroy

Comment: @BigGenius you should **not** crosspost

Comment: Sorry, i will not do it again.

Comment: @BigGenius jftr some discussion about [crossposting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: @BigGenius You force apt to use your repo by putting it as the only repository in you sources.list

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a repository based on the packages. You can easily do it with [dpkg-scanpackages](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dpkg-scanpackages&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en), e.g:

```
dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null | gzip > Packages.gz
echo "deb file:/path/to/directory ./" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/local-mirror.list
apt-get update
```

This will allow you to use the files from your local mirror. For a more verbose example have a look at the [Ubuntu personal repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal) manual.

Comment: I did this, but still ubuntu install them from remote repos, instead of local repos. How do i force it to install these depencies from my repo?

Comment: @BigGenius remove the remote repository from your sources.list

Comment: is this only way out? Can i force it instead?

Comment: @BigGenius You can use [apt pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) as well. Another solution is to place the `file` lines before any other line, e.g. in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or rename the file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to `000-local.list`